# Is it possible to have a single field of an object, in an array, be unique in that array?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a json object that looks something like this:

```
{
    "groups": [ 
        {
            "id":"1",
            "members": "joe,karen"
        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "members": "joe,karen"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way in json schema to say that the `id` field needs to be unique across all objects in groups, but not other fields (`members`)?

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not have restrictions on values in json-schema, except if you use enum values.

[But This might work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475427/need-help-json-schema-design).